# Centos 5 Apache WHM Cpanel Server Limit, Max Clients

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5

Hello today my VPS server goes down, the node have this:
2GB RAM
1/2 CPU
40 GB Storage
The Server Limit and Max Clients as default:
Server Limit: 256
Max Clients: 150

So .. i set the  node to:
RAM 8GB
2 CPUs
160 GB Storage

The "Server Limit" and "Max Clients" still having default values
My question.. exists any table or something, to change the "Server Limit"
and the "Max Clients" for the new hardware

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These limits control the number of simultaneous clients apache can handle.  Having these values too low would not cause a server to crash.  In fact, low values often prevent a server from crashing by limiting traffic.

You will want to check the apache error logs:

/usr/local/apache/logs

To see if there is a warning about MaxClients.  If there is no warning, then you do not need to adjust these values.

cPanel VPS purposely sets this low to help prevent system crashes.

There is no rule of thumb as each server is unique.  Rely on the logs to see if you need to increase it.

More likely, your server ran out of RAM.  Check google for "sysstat" and make sure it is installed and learn how to use the "sar" command to get more info about your server's performance metrics.